How to set custom tmp directory for Hadoop
We are using Hadoop version 2.10.2 and facing below error while starting  server. Due to company security policy no execution permission is set on /tmp directory hence library libleveldbjni-64-1-7115603708108814032.8 can't be loaded from there. Is there any way to resolve this?
I have tried adding below configuration for custom temp directory under core-site.xml located in /opt/osa/hadoop-2.10.2/etc/hadoop. Also, restarted hadoop server and formatted the name node but still custom tmp_Hadoop directory is empty.
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/opt/osa/hadoop-2.10.2/tmp_Hadoop</value> 
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description> 
</property>

Logs Message:  2024-06-13 09:57:00,871 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni in java.library.path, /tmp/libleveldbjni-64-1-7115603708108814032.8: /tmp/libleveldbjni-64-1-7115603708108814032.8: failed to map segment from shared object]
at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:182)
at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:140)
at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory.<clinit>(JniDBFactory.java:48)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.recovery.NMLeveldbStateStoreService.openDatabase(NMLeveldbStateStoreService.java:1699)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.recovery.NMLeveldbStateStoreService.initStorage(NMLeveldbStateStoreService.java:1687)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.recovery.NMStateStoreService.serviceInit(NMStateStoreService.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartRecoveryStore(NodeManager.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:358)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:878)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:946)
2024-06-13 09:57:00,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state STOPPED; cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2024-06-13 10:33:36,622 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:


Thanks for the clarification. Could you try adding the following java option to YARN Node Manager startup script -Dlibrary.leveldbjni.path=/opt/osa/hadoop-2.10.2/tmp_Hadoop (or whatever path you want to use) and restart the NMs? I think LevelDB JNI uses this setting or, if not set, java.io.tmpdir. But the latter obviously affects everything running within JVM.
